# Database design - Similar Contact Information for multiple entities

Tags: database-design, relational-database, contacts, erd

I realise that the answer to these types of questions are often "it depends" but still I wondering what the general consensus might be.

I am dealing with multiple entities such as

1. Company
2. Charity
3. Auditor
4. Stocktaker

etc etc...

Which all have contact information such as e-mail, telephone and address.

The two design methods I was thinking to store the contact info were

Method 1) create role tables between the contact tables and company, charity, auditor and stocktaker.

- dbo.Company -> dbo.CompanyAddress <- dbo.Address
- dbo.Company -> dbo.Companytelephone <- dbo.telephone
- dbo.Company -> dbo.Companyaddress <- dbo.email
- dbo.Auditor-> dbo.AuditorAddress <- dbo.Address
- dbo.Auditor-> dbo.Auditortelephone <- dbo.telephone
- dbo.Auditor-> dbo.Auditoraddress <- dbo.email

Advantages, there only needs to be one address, telephone and email table in database and all telephone numbers, addresses and emails for each entity type are stored in one place
Disadvantages are it creates a lot of associative tables

Method 2) Create a separate contact table per company, charity, auditor and stocktaker

- dbo.Company -> dbo.CompanyContactAddress
- dbo.Company -> dbo.CompanyContacttelephone
- dbo.Company -> dbo.CompanyContactaddress
- dbo.Auditor -> dbo.AuditorContactAddress
- dbo.Auditor -> dbo.AuditorContacttelephone
- dbo.Auditor -> dbo.AuditorContactaddress

Advantages of this are easier to implement and maintain
Disadvantages are contact details are stored in multiple locations across the database.

If anyone has any other ideas it would be much appreciated.

Many thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are correct when you say "it depends". It depends on what your data will be used for OLTP you would look at a normalized design, and a reporting system you would want the data de-normalized with the contact information inline with the other data components.

In the normalized database, the level of normalization can also be debated. Some will say to have contact information granular like you have in your first scenario. I like to go "middle of the road" I would have all contact information in one table, which included address, telephone and email.

```
Contact
ID, Address, Address2, City, State, Zip, Phone, Email
```

Then create a relationship with a separate table

```
CompanyContact
ID, CompanyID, ContactID
```

This too could be integrated into the company table, by just adding a `ContactID` to the Company table and avoid the separate relationship and join.

You could also implement a table with `ContactTypes`.

```
ContactType 
ID, ContactType
1, Company
2, Charity
3, Auditor
....
```

Then you could specify that in the `CompanyContact` table and remove the need for a relationship. Although it fits your scenario of 1 contact per type it does not leave room for growth.

Comment: Cheers Dustin. I like the middle of the road idea. I think I'll use this idea but I would need to move out address as potentially various entities could have tens of addresses. Cheers for the advise.

Answer (score 0):

I like your method 2 better, but it still seems too much work. Why not just have a PhoneNumber, Address, etc... tables that store ALL addresses, phone numbers, whatevers, then reference that from the Company, Auditor, etc...? It's probably how I would have done it.

Comment: I did consider this method but assuming I have 10 different entities that all link to the contacttelephone table for example this would then create 10 FK columns in contacttelephone table with 9 nulls each time.

Comment: @FairFunk: I'm not sure I get it... why would there be a key in ContactTelephone back to the entity? Shouldn't the keys be in the other direction, from the entity to the ContactTelephone? Well, if you really wanted a back-link you could have the entity ID and then another field telling you which entity table to look at, so you'd only have 2 FK columns in ContactTelephone instead of 10.

Answer (score 0):

You could use a single table for all and use data types like below. 
[image]

Comment: What database is this in? Not all databases support UDTs.

Comment: No UDTs involved but this one is a SQLite db