# Database design - Multiple "Contact information" for different tables

Tags: database, database-design, relational-database, contacts

I have a database with tables "person", "company", "shop", etc. Many of these tables must have "contact information". The possibility to design this was asked in [Database design - Similar Contact Information for multiple entities](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3636061/database-design-similar-contact-information-for-multiple-entities)
Now, in my database **I leave a possibility to have a multiple addresses, multiple phones and multiple emails to each contact data**. This is my database schema:

[image: database contact information]

So, **I make an intermediate table "contact" as a simplest way to link a "contact information" to each table.**
**My question: is it a good practice to do this and to have a table with only one row?**

Comment: Only one Row or only one Column?

Answer (score 8):

This is how I would design your database:

```
address_types
    id              unsigned int(P)
    description     varchar(10) // Mailing, Physical, etc.

addresses
    id              unsigned int(P)
    line1           varchar(50) // 123 Main Street, etc.
    line2           varchar(50) // Default NULL
    city_id         unsigned int(F cities.id)
    zip             varchar(6) // 12345, A1A 1A1, etc.
    zip4            char(4) // Default NULL
    lat             decimal(10,8) // 13.12345678, etc.
    lon             decimal(11,8) // 110.12345678, etc.

cities
    id              unsigned int(P)
    state_id        unsigned int(F states.id)
    name            varchar(50) // Omaha, Detroit, Tampa, etc.

companies
    id              unsigned int(P)
    name            varchar(75) // IBM, Microsoft, RedHat, etc.
    ...

companies_addresses
    id                  unsigned int(P)
    company_id          unsigned int(F companies.id)
    address_id          unsigned int(F addresses.id)
    address_type_id     unsigned int(F address_types.id)

companies_contacts
    id                  unsigned int(P)
    company_id          unsigned int(F companies.id)
    contact_id          unsigned int(F contacts.id)
    contact_type_id     unsigned int(F contact_types.id)

companies_emails
    id                  unsigned int(P)
    company_id          unsigned int(F companies.id)
    email_id            unsigned int(F emails.id)
    email_type_id       unsigned int(F email_types.id)

contact_types
    id              unsigned int(P)
    description     varchar(10) // Home phone, Mobile phone, FAX, etc.
```

In North America phone numbers look like this: CC-AAA-EEE-SSSS-XXXXXXX where CC is the country code, AAA is the area code, EEE is the exchange, SSSS is the station and XXXXX is the extension.

```
contacts
    id              unsigned int(P)
    country_code    varchar(3)
    area_code       varchar(3)
    exchange        varchar(3)
    station         varchar(4)
    extension       varchar(10) // Default NULL
```

See [ISO 3166-1](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_3166-1_alpha-2).

```
countries
    id              char(2) // ca, mx, us, etc.
    iso3            char(3) // can, mex, usa, etc.
    iso_num         char(3)
    name            varchar(44) // Canada, Mexico, United States, etc.

email_types
    id              unsigned int(P)
    description     varchar(10) // Personal, Work, etc.

emails
    id              unsigned int(P)
    address         varchar(255) // support@ibm.com, etc.

shops
    id              unsigned int(P)
    name            varchar(45) // Shop A, Shop B, etc.
    ...

shops_addresses
    id                  unsigned int(P)
    shop_id             unsigned int(F shops.id)
    address_id          unsigned int(F addresses.id)
    address_type_id     unsigned int(F address_types.id)

shops_contacts
    id                  unsigned int(P)
    shop_id             unsigned int(F shops.id)
    contact_id          unsigned int(F contacts.id)
    contact_type_id     unsigned int(F contact_types.id)

shops_emails
    id                      unsigned int(P)
    shop_id                 unsigned int(F shops.id)
    email_id                unsigned int(F emails.id)
    email_type_id           unsigned int(F email_types.id)
```

See [ISO 3166-2](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_3166-2).

```
states
    id              unsigned int(P)
    country_id      char(2)(F countries.id)
    code            varchar(2) // AL, NF, NL, etc.
    name            varchar(50) // Alabama, Newfoundland, Nuevo León, etc.
```

Comment: Ok, I see your point. You propose the same solution that here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3636061/database-design-similar-contact-information-for-multiple-entities (method 1). But here a same disadvantage – "creation a lot of associative tables". There is another way to do this?

Comment: It's really not a disadvantage, normalization is a good thing. RDBMS's are good at joining tables as long as you index things properly.

Comment: I know this is 2 years old, but I'm wondering what your thoughts are for putting the `email_type_id` on each of the `XXXX_emails` tables rather than putting it on the `email` table since every email will have a type. I'm designing something similar and came to a similar design as you (with the exception of not breaking the phone number out into as many columns), except that I was going to put the email_type_id on the email table.

Comment: @kralco626 - two years later I would design this slightly differently. I would put the `email_type_id` in the `emails` table as you suggest but I would also remove the `id` column from the `shops_addresses`, `shops_contacts` and `shops_emails` tables. I would change their respective primary keys to be a composite of `shop_id` and `address_id`; `shop_id` and `contact_id`; and `shop_id` and `email_id`.

Answer (score 3):

> My question: is it a good practice to do this and to have a table with only one row?

Not really. Looking at your diagram, I have to ask : can a contact really be linked to an arbitrary number of persons ? If not, you should use 'person' as your parent table and make the other tables link to it.

Comment: Actually yes, I can have a thousand persons, companies and shops. If I understand well your advice, I have to link directly email, phone and address to all my entities (persons, companies, shops)? So I will have something like this:
`email ->
idemail, mail, idperson, idcompany, idshop`
Is it really better?

Comment: No, in your case you should in fact use associative tables as suggested by Benny Hill below. It is possible to do otherwise, but insuring the data stays coherent would be really annoying and not worth it.

Comment: also link country to address not to city, as there may be cities in different countries and/or states/province/county that has same name

Answer (score 2):

Personaly, i don't like realy this method because we need to create any Entity for each table and a lot of associative tables. I propose one table for contact informations and another one for addresses.

```
informations
- id INT
- name VARCHAR
- value VARCHAR
- type ENUM(phone, email, url, custom)
- idcompany INT NULL
- idcontact INT NULL
```

And

```
addresses
- id
- address1
- address2
- district
- postcode
- idcity
- idcompany
- idcontact
```